# See what has been passed to a Mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a mostly working unit test that checks a method is called, which works fine.  However I would like to check the parameters that are passed to that method.  Using `Verify` I can check if a particular set of arguments are passed, but if these are not passed and the test fails, is there a way of seeing what was actually passed to the method?

Example:

```
sut.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<myClass>()).Verifiable();
sut.Object.DoAThing();
sut.Verify(x => x.MyMethod(It.Is<myClass>(v => v.thing == 1)));
```

In my test this will fail (`v.thing` will be something other than 1), but what I would like to know is, what IS `v.thing` set to?  I'd like to know as I find this kind of feedback really helpful in debugging my code and unit tests.

The error I am getting is simply saying that x.MyMethod (with those expected parameters) was never called.

Is there a solution? am I missing something obvious?

Minimal Example to illustrate my point:

```
public class myClass
{
    public struct myStruct {
        public int thing;
    }
    public virtual void MyMethod(myStruct x )
    {
        // Code goes here
    }
}

public class sutClass
{
    public myClass target = new myClass();
    public void DoAThing()
    {
        myClass.myStruct toBePassed = new myClass.myStruct { thing = 8 };

        target.MyMethod(toBePassed);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    Mock<myClass> mMyClass = new Mock<myClass>();
    sutClass sut = new sutClass();
    sut.target = mMyClass.Object;

    mMyClass.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<myClass.myStruct>())).Verifiable();

    sut.DoAThing();

    mMyClass.Verify(x => x.MyMethod(It.Is<myClass.myStruct>(v => v.thing == 1)));
}
```

The above simple test will obviously return a fail.

```
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.MyMethod(It.Is<myStruct>(v => v.thing == 1))
```

What I would like to see is an output of what WAS passed to `MyMethod` what was the difference between what was expected and what actually happened.  Much like `Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)` would return.  (the expected string and the actual string for example).

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand your problem.

Comment: I have updated to provide example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a callback in your mock setup:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Mock<myClass> mMyClass = new Mock<myClass>();
        sutClass sut = new sutClass();
        sut.target = mMyClass.Object;

        int passedValue = 0;

        mMyClass.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<myClass.myStruct>())).Callback<myClass.myStruct>((s) => { passedValue = s.thing; Console.Write(s.thing); });

        sut.DoAThing();

        mMyClass.Verify(x => x.MyMethod(It.Is<myClass.myStruct>(v => v.thing == 1)));
    }
```

Here the value is set to passedValue and printed to the console

Comment: I can work with that thanks!  I have modified my test to check the calls within Verify and then using your answer tested the values of what was passed individually with `Assert.AreEqual`.  This allows me to see which of the values are failing the test.  :)